# Integrating FusionCharts with Metronic template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, fusioncharts

I am trying to display a fusion chart on a metronic template but it is showing a blank page after integrating it.

Comment: Do you have any code examples?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood [metronic template](https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469) is a template engine working on Bootstrap 3.3.5 Framework, jQuery 1.10.2 and lots more. I provide you a sample which uses FusionCharts with bootstrap and see how it works.Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyanGhatak/T5C6h/1561/) Try your code out here and see if it works.

One probable reason for you, showing a blank page, might be scripts are not loaded in proper order. Check console, you might get an error "FusionCharts is not defined".

An illustrative JS snippet to render a line chart in FusionCharts:

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'msline',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '550',
        height: '350',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Number of visitors last week",
                "subCaption": "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d",
                "bgcolor": "#ffffff",
                "legendBgColor": "#d9ffb3",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "showShadow": "0",
                "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                "legendShadow": "0",
                "showAxisLines": "0",
                "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                "divlineThickness": "1",
                "divLineIsDashed": "1",
                "divLineDashLen": "1",
                "divLineGapLen": "1",
                "xAxisName": "Day",
                "showValues": "0"               
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "category": [
                        { "label": "Mon" }, 
                        { "label": "Tue" }, 
                        { "label": "Wed" },
                        {
                            "vline": "true",
                            "lineposition": "0",
                            "color": "#6baa01",
                            "labelHAlign": "center",
                            "labelPosition": "0",
                            "label": "National holiday",
                            "dashed":"1"
                        },
                        { "label": "Thu" }, 
                        { "label": "Fri" }, 
                        { "label": "Sat" }, 
                        { "label": "Sun" }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "seriesname": "Bakersfield Central",
                    "data": [
                        { "value": "15123" }, 
                        { "value": "14233" }, 
                        { "value": "25507" }, 
                        { "value": "9110" }, 
                        { "value": "15529" }, 
                        { "value": "20803" }, 
                        { "value": "19202" }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesname": "Los Angeles Topanga",
                    "data": [
                        { "value": "13400" }, 
                        { "value": "12800" }, 
                        { "value": "22800" }, 
                        { "value": "12400" }, 
                        { "value": "15800" }, 
                        { "value": "19800" }, 
                        { "value": "21800" }
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "trendlines": [
                {
                    "line": [
                        {
                            "startvalue": "17022",
                            "color": "#6baa01",
                            "valueOnRight": "1",
                            "displayvalue": "Average"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }).render();
});
```